# Test run crashes OS

Tags: windows, task-manager, visual-studio, postgresql, resharper

This sometimes happens on Windows 10 when I'm running NUnit tests which use postgresql from ReSharper test runner. The test doesn't finish and I see a very strange behavior in all applications.

Specifying any (even non-existing) process never returns:

```
taskkill /f /im sldfksflkdkf3.exe
```

But just

```
taskkill
```

prints "incorrect syntax".

- I also can't launch a task manager.
- I can't close Visual Studio or stop the test but the UI is responsible.
- Nothing happens when I'm trying to launch anything "as administrator" or another user.
- Start menu doesn't work.
- Context menu on taskbar doesn't work but I still can switch windows and launch apps except task manager.
- `services.msc` doesn't open but `sc query` works.
- I can't logout or shutdown.
- Disk access works normally - checked with notepad.

What (technically) can cause this?

Comment: Lots can cause it, we know, nothing about your unit tests

Comment: @Ramhound lots? Personally I don't have any idea of which code could cause all such effects at the same time on system level and without elevating.